# Creating Group and User for Tomcat RHEL/CentOS

Tags: centos, software-installation, chown, useradd, tomcat

I want to create an user for my Tomcat installation, but I was viewing multiple options:

```
# groupadd tomcat
#
# useradd -g tomcat -d /usr/local/tomcat tomcat
# useradd -g tomcat -c "Tomcat User" -d /usr/local/tomcat tomcat
```

Other alternative:

https://panovski.me/install-tomcat-8-on-centos-7/

```
# useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin tomcat
# chown -R tomcat: /usr/local/tomcat
```

In other page (hidden and recursive)

```
# useradd -r tomcat --shell /bin/false
# chown -hR tomcat: /usr/local/tomcat
```

Other option:?

```
# useradd -g tomcat -s /bin/bash -d /usr/local/tomcat tomcat
# chown -Rf tomcat.tomcat /usr/local/tomcat
```

I don't know what is the mistake or consequence, I want to know what is the best option

I think is best to use -h hidden, but

*chown* - change file owner and group

```
-r, --system
  Create a system account.

  System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow, and their 
  numeric identifiers are chosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX range, defined in
  /etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and their GID counterparts for the
  creation of groups).

  Note that useradd will not create a home directory for such an user, regardless
  of the default setting in /etc/login.defs (CREATE_HOME). You have to specify the
  -m options if you want a home directory for a system account to be created.

-s, --shell SHELL
  The name of the user's login shell. The default is to leave this field blank,
  which causes the system to select the default login shell specified by the SHELL
  variable in /etc/default/useradd, or an empty string by default.
```

**In CentOS is needed to use -s or -r options?**

**EDIT 2**

```
# useradd -r UserL5C --shell /bin/false
# more /etc/passwd | grep UserL5C
UserL5C:x:494:491::/home/UserL5C:/bin/false
# more /etc/group | grep UserL5C
UserL5C:x:491:
# finger UserL5C
Login: UserL5C                  Name: 
Directory: /home/UserL5C                Shell: /bin/false
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
#
```

*UserL5C* with UID and GID lower than 500

```
# useradd UserG5C --shell /bin/false
# more /etc/passwd | grep UserG5C
UserG5C:x:503:504::/home/UserG5C:/bin/false
# more /etc/group | grep UserG5C
UserG5C:x:504:
# finger UserG5C
Login: UserG5C                  Name: 
Directory: /home/UserG5C                Shell: /bin/false
Never logged in.
No mail.
No Plan.
#
```

*UserG5C* UID and GID greater than 500

```
# ls -al /home/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root       root        4096 Jun 25 06:05 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root       root        4096 Jun 25 05:19 ..
drwx------. 33 IntUser    IntUser     4096 Jun 25 05:46 IntUser
drwx------.  2 root       root       16384 Jun 13 09:56 lost+found
drwx------.  4 UserG5C    UserG5C     4096 Jun 25 06:01 UserG5C
#
```

The difference *UserG5C* creates homeDirectory

**Question**

It would be better to use:   *useradd UserG5C -M -s /bin/false* because this user/account hasn't system privileges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are as many opinions as there are people.
I think the best way to create tomcat user to do as follows:

```
# useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin tomcat
# chown -R tomcat: /usr/local/tomcat
```

It means, you will create system account. Info from `man useradd`:

```
System users will be created with no aging information in /etc/shadow,
and their numeric identifiers are chosen in the SYS_UID_MIN-SYS_UID_MAX
range, defined in /etc/login.defs, instead of UID_MIN-UID_MAX (and their
GID counterparts for the creation of groups).
```

Also `useradd -r ...` creates the group with the same name as user and you don't need to create in by yourself.

BTW, if you'll decide to change something in user configuration (for example: specify home directory, or change shell), you will always can do it with `usermod` command.

Read `man useradd` and `man usermod`.

**Edit**

Really you should answer some questions:

1. Do you need system user (with UID < 500)?
2. Do you need shell or you want to disable shell access (`/sbin/nologin, /bin/false`)?
3. Do you need home directory for that user (BTW, tomcat possibly want to 
   have it)?

Ok, you don't want UID < 500 and want home directory (it's not exists now), let's do the following command:

```
# useradd -U -d /usr/local/tomcat -m -s /bin/false tomcat
```

Option `-U` will create the group with same name.
If you want add user description, use `-c "Tomcat user"`.

If you already have the tomcat directory:

```
# useradd -U -d /usr/local/tomcat -M -s /bin/false tomcat
```

After that you should change the owner for tomcat directory (to allow tomcat user to work with it):

```
# chown -R tomcat: /usr/local/tomcat
```

**Edit 2**

You've asked, we are answering.

1. If your user has UID < 500 it only means it's the user for some service, not ordinary user (possibly human, who has shell access). It won't bring you the vulnerability because these users are not treated specially by operating system. Also it won't give you extended functionality. Only one thing why it's not good to use UIDs < 500: you can install some RPM-package in future and it will provide the user with the same UID. In that case you'll have some issues. That's it! BTW, tomcat installed from RPM provides user tomcat with UID=91 and group with GID=91 (at least in my Fedora):

```
$ id tomcat
uid=91(tomcat) gid=91(tomcat) groups=91(tomcat)
```

2. Ok, use `/bin/false` or `/sbin/nologin`.
3. You can specify `/` as home directory for your service like some packages do. For example, if you have tcpdump installed from RPM, you have the following string in `/etc/passwd`:

```
tcpdump:x:72:72::/:/sbin/nologin
```

In this case use `useradd` command with keys `-d /` and `-M`.

In other hand, tomcat installed from RPM, has correct home directory:

```
tomcat:x:91:91:Apache Tomcat:/usr/share/tomcat:/bin/nologin
```

And now few words about `chown`.

These commands does the same job:

```
chown tomcat:tomcat /usr/local/tomcat
chown tomcat: /usr/local/tomcat
```

Quotation from `man chown`:

> Group is unchanged if missing, but changed to login group if
>          implied by a ':' following a symbolic OWNER.

Using `.` as OWNER/GROUP separator is deprecated now. Use `:`.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope, it will help you.

Comment: Answers: 1) I don't know, I think that UID means System User and vice versa. I have doubts. If I haven't System User maybe I loss functionality, but I have it then I will have vulnerability.  2) I think the shell isn't needed. 3) I think doesn't need homeDirectory although have ownership over tomcat directory.

Comment: New edit added. Enjoy!

Comment: The last question is: has it `# useradd -r -d /usr/local/tomcat -s /sbin/nologin tomcat` sense?. In other words,  to use *-r* together with *-d*?

Comment: Yes, it make sense to use these keys together. If you omit `-d` key, the home directory will be specified as `/home/tomcat` in `/etc/passwd`. If you want to change this behavior, you should use `-d`.

Comment: According to this website: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/ uid from 1-99 should be to predefined accounts...so isn't it wrong to put tomcat on uid 91?

Comment: It's not wrong because these accounts usually predefined by Linux distribution developers. Fedora project developers decided to assign uid 91 to tomcat - ok, no problem. The tomcat package can be installed "out of the box" with Fedora Linux, so user tomcat is predefined. If you want to install tomcat manually from tarball (with manually created user) it's better to choose uid > 99.

Comment: ohhh interesting, I didn't know they reserved these uids to services from outside linux itself. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
useradd -m -d /home/thenewuser -s /bin/bash -c "the new user" -U thenewuser
```

*-c "message"* : extra information about the user.

*-U thenewuser* :  Create a group with the same name as the user, and add the user to this group.

*-N* : the -N argument tells the system not to create a group having the user’s name

*-m, --create-home* are same:  Create the user's home directory if it does not exist.

*-d, --home HOME_DIR* : The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the user's login directory.
if *-d* is not used the default homedirectory will be /home/thenewuser

*-m -d /data/thenewuser* : the *-m* argument creates the /data/thenewuser homedirectory, specified by the -d argument.

*-M* : the -M argument tells the system not to create a home directory

*-s /bin/bash* : the *-s* is used for specifing the user’s default shell, /bin/bash in this case.

*-s or --shell* are same.

*-s /sbin/nologin* : The */sbin/nologin* for Fedora and */usr/sbin/nologin* for Debian are two shells that return you a polite message like “this account is not available” and do not allow you to log into the system. This message can be customized.

*-s /bin/false* : Is an old shell used to deny a user’s login. The /bin/false exits immediatly when false exists. The user accounts with /bin/false or /bin/true as their default shells are locked.

*-s /sbin/nologin* belongs to unix-linux while /bin/false part of GNU Coreutils. These shells must be listed in the /etc/shells file, to work.

The users with /sbin/nologin (or /usr/sbin/nologin) can connect through ssh or ftp, but the users with /bin/false are completely locked out from the system.

with *useradd -D* : You can also view the default parameters set for new user to be created using

```
# useradd -D
GROUP=100
HOME=/home
INACTIVE=-1
EXPIRE=
SHELL=/bin/bash
SKEL=/etc/skel
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes
#
```

Check another alternatives in: http://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/04/10-practical-examples-to-use-useradd.html

*-r* : the -r arguments is for creating a system user

**Check user**

*finger*

Example

```
# finger mysql
  Login: mysql                      Name: 
  Directory: /home/mysql            Shell: /bin/bash
  Never logged in.
  No mail.
  No Plan.
#
```

CentOS 6 doesn't have this command, but you can easily install it with

> yum install finger

.

`other`  *`* http://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/

Comment: If a user name or UID is followed directly by a colon or dot but no group name is provided, then the group is changed to that user's login group. Thus, for example, the following would change the ownership of file3 to cathy and would also change that file's group to the login group of the new owner (which by default is usually the same as the new owner):

    chown cathy: file3
http://www.linfo.org/chown.html
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/chown-examples/
http://askubuntu.com/questions/628896/chown-difference-between-user-and-useruser

Answer (score -1):

```
useradd -m -c "Tomcat User" -s /bin/nologin -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
tar -xvf apache-tomcat-9.0.53.tar.gz -C /opt/tomcat --strip-components=1
chown -R tomcat: /opt/tomcat
sh -c 'chmod +x /opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).